# Email-to-Case won't generate case record

Tags: email, email2case, servicecloud

I'm trying to create a case via Email but it won't generate a record in Case. I already configured the Email-to-Case settings, the Email Id is already verified, and I already checked the Support Settings and the Record type settings and also I already added the long email address as forwarding email in gmail. I also tried to used both the Email Address and Service Email Address.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you use the long address, then check your debug logs (Using the user that is the Automated Case user in Setup) to see what error is generated. Note - that user will get email indicating the error

Comment: Try to check this article - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384980&type=1